# Rails: Is there an equivalent to save_without_validation which skips after_save filters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, after-save

I have an after_save filter which I dont want to trigger in a specific instance.  Is there a way to do this similar to save_without_validation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

When using rails 2, you can invoke the private method `create_without_callbacks` by doing:

```
@my_obj.send(:create_without_callbacks)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example of extending ActiveRecord to provide callback skipping here: http://weareintegrum.com/?p=10

The idea is to create a method on ActiveRecord called skip_callback that accepts a block:

```
def self.skip_callback(callback, &block)
  method = instance_method(callback)
  remove_method(callback) if respond_to?(callback)
  define_method(callback){ true }
  begin
    result = yield
  ensure
    remove_method(callback)
    define_method(callback, method)
  end
  result
end
```

Then anything you do within the block does not execute the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can set and reset callbacks like this:

```
  Post.after_update.reject! {|callback| callback.method.to_s == 'fancy_callback_on_update' }
  Post.after_create.reject! {|callback| callback.method.to_s == 'fancy_callback_on_create' }

  Post.after_create :fancy_callback_on_create
  Post.after_update :fancy_callback_on_update
```

You can add these around your custom `save` method.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 2, you can also use the following methods:

`create_without_callbacks` or `update_without_callbacks`